# D3 V4: Updated data is being seen as new data? (Update function)

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, updates

Currently, I am building a system, and I am having some trouble with the update function.

Essentially, I am trying to add new nodes to a D3 tree. A new child node can be added when the user clicks the "add button" of a node. Each add button can be found on the left side of each node.

I have followed Mike Bostock's [general update pattern](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808234). Once I click on the button, the only "new" data element should be the newly created child node, but it looks like the entire data is being treat as "new". I came to this conclusion when I looked at the class names for each node and the obvious fact that there is a transition of all the nodes coming to the central node and disappearing. The other original data should be "updated", but it's not. Can anyone please gently point out as to why this is happening?

A working sample of my code can be found in this [jfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/hd537t14/13/).

**EDIT 06/09**

Given Gordon's suggestion, I have found a unique field for both of my nodes and link. So to uniquely identify the data I have made the following change:

NODE

```
.data(d, d => d.data.name)
```

LINK

```
.data(d, d => d.source.data.name)
```

This change works (mostly), but I see that some weird behaviors are still occurring: (1) Branch 7.2.1 is still being recognized a new node and disappear; (2) links are not being properly aligned with their respective node after the second "add" or so. I think my two small edits are affecting this because when I went back to the original code, the lines are being properly drawn, despite the fact they're transitioning away. Thoughts? Advice?

---

**HTML**

```
  <div id="div-mindMap">
```

**CSS**

```
.linkMindMap {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #555;
    stroke-opacity: 0.4;
}    
rect {
    fill: white;
    stroke: #3182bd;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;  
 }
```

**JS**

```
const widthMindMap = 700;
const heightMindMap = 700;
let parsedData;

let parsedList = {
  "name": " Stapler",
  "children": [{
      "name": " Bind",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "   Nail",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "   String",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": " Glue",
      "children": [{
          "name": "Gum",
          "children": []
        },
        {
          "name": "Sticky Gum",
          "children": []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": " Branch 3",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": " Branch 4",
      "children": [{
          "name": "   Branch 4.1",
          "children": []
        },
        {
          "name": "   Branch 4.2",
          "children": []
        },
        {
          "name": "   Branch 4.1",
          "children": []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": " Branch 5",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": " Branch 6",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": " Branch 7",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "   Branch 7.1",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "   Branch 7.2",
      "children": [{
          "name": "   Branch 7.2.1",
          "children": []
        },
        {
          "name": "   Branch 7.2.1",
          "children": []
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}


let svgMindMap = d3.select('#div-mindMap')
  .append("svg")
  .attr("id", "svg-mindMap")
  .attr("width", widthMindMap)
  .attr("height", heightMindMap);


let backgroundLayer = svgMindMap.append('g')
  .attr("width", widthMindMap)
  .attr("height", heightMindMap)
  .attr("class", "background")

let gLeft = backgroundLayer.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + widthMindMap / 2 + ",0)")
  .attr("class", "g-left");
let gLeftLink = gLeft.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'g-left-link');
let gLeftNode = gLeft.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'g-left-node');


function loadMindMap(parsed) {
  var data = parsed;
  var split_index = Math.round(data.children.length / 2);

  parsedData = {
    "name": data.name,
    "children": JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data.children.slice(split_index)))
  };

  var left = d3.hierarchy(parsedData, d => d.children);

  drawLeft(left, "left");
}

// draw single tree
function drawLeft(root, pos) {
  var SWITCH_CONST = 1;
  if (pos === "left") SWITCH_CONST = -1;

  update(root, SWITCH_CONST);
}

function update(source, SWITCH_CONST) {
  var tree = d3.tree()
    .size([heightMindMap, SWITCH_CONST * (widthMindMap - 150) / 2]);
  var root = tree(source);

  console.log(root)

  var nodes = root.descendants();
  var links = root.links();

  console.log(nodes)
  console.log(links)
  // Set both root nodes to be dead center vertically
  nodes[0].x = heightMindMap / 2

  //JOIN new data with old elements
  var link = gLeftLink.selectAll(".link-left")
    .data(links, d => d)
    .style('stroke-width', 1.5);

  var linkEnter = link.enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", "linkMindMap link-left")
    .attr("d", d3.linkHorizontal()
      .x(d => d.y)
      .y(d => d.x));

  var linkUpdate = linkEnter.merge(link);

  linkUpdate.transition()
    .duration(750)
  var linkExit = link.exit()
    .transition()
    .duration(750)
    .attr('x1', function(d) {
      return root.x;
    })
    .attr('y1', function(d) {
      return root.y;
    })
    .attr('x2', function(d) {
      return root.x;
    })
    .attr('y2', function(d) {
      return root.y;
    })
    .remove();

  //JOIN new data with old elements
  var node = gLeftNode.selectAll(".nodeMindMap-left")
    .data(nodes, d => d);

  console.log(nodes);


  //ENTER new elements present in new data
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g").merge(node)
    .attr("class", function(d) {
      return "nodeMindMap-left " + "nodeMindMap" + (d.children ? " node--internal" : " node--leaf");
    })
    .classed("enter", true)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
    })
    .attr("id", function(d) {
      let str = d.data.name;
      str = str.replace(/\s/g, '');
      return str;
    });

  nodeEnter.append("circle")
    .attr("r", function(d, i) {
      return 2.5
    });

  var addLeftChild = nodeEnter.append("g")
    .attr("class", "addHandler")
    .attr("id", d => {
      let str = d.data.name;
      str = "addHandler-" + str.replace(/\s/g, '');
      return str;
    })
    .style("opacity", "1")
    .on("click", (d, i, nodes) => addNewLeftChild(d, i, nodes));

  addLeftChild.append("line")
    .attr("x1", -74)
    .attr("y1", 1)
    .attr("x2", -50)
    .attr("y2", 1)
    .attr("stroke", "#85e0e0")
    .style("stroke-width", "2");

  addLeftChild.append("rect")
    .attr("x", "-77")
    .attr("y", "-7")
    .attr("height", 15)
    .attr("width", 15)
    .attr("rx", 5)
    .attr("ry", 5)
    .style("stroke", "#444")
    .style("stroke-width", "1")
    .style("fill", "#ccc");

  addLeftChild.append("line")
    .attr("x1", -74)
    .attr("y1", 1)
    .attr("x2", -65)
    .attr("y2", 1)
    .attr("stroke", "#444")
    .style("stroke-width", "1.5");

  addLeftChild.append("line")
    .attr("x1", -69.5)
    .attr("y1", -3)
    .attr("x2", -69.5)
    .attr("y2", 5)
    .attr("stroke", "#444")
    .style("stroke-width", "1.5");

  // .call(d3.drag().on("drag", dragged));;

  nodeEnter.append("foreignObject")
    .style("fill", "blue")
    .attr("x", -50)
    .attr("y", -7)
    .attr("height", "20px")
    .attr("width", "100px")
    .append('xhtml:div')
    .append('div')
    .attr("class", 'clickable-node')
    .attr("id", function(d) {
      let str = d.data.name;
      str = "div-" + str.replace(/\s/g, '');
      return str;
    })
    .attr("ondblclick", "this.contentEditable=true")
    .attr("onblur", "this.contentEditable=false")
    .attr("contentEditable", "false")
    .style("text-align", "center")
    .text(d => d.data.name);

  //TODO: make it dynamic
  nodeEnter.insert("rect", "foreignObject")
    .attr("ry", 6)
    .attr("rx", 6)
    .attr("y", -10)
    .attr("height", 20)
    .attr("width", 100)
    // .filter(function(d) { return d.flipped; })
    .attr("x", -50)
    .classed("selected", false)
    .attr("id", function(d) {
      let str = d.data.name;
      str = "rect-" + str.replace(/\s/g, '');
      return str;
    });

  var nodeUpdate = nodeEnter.merge(node);
  // Transition to the proper position for the node
  nodeUpdate.transition()
    .duration(750)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
    });

  // Remove any exiting nodes
  var nodeExit = node.exit()
    .transition()
    .duration(750)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
    })
    .remove();

  // On exit reduce the node circles size to 0
  nodeExit.select('circle').attr('r', 0);
  // node = nodeEnter.merge(node)
}

function addNewLeftChild(d, i, nodes) {
  console.log("make new child");
  event.stopPropagation();
  var newNodeObj = {
    // name: new Date().getTime(),
    name: "New Child",
    children: []
  };

  console.log("this is ", parsedData)
  //Creates new Node
  var newNode = d3.hierarchy(newNodeObj);
  newNode.depth = d.depth + 1;
  newNode.height = d.height - 1;
  newNode.parent = d;
  newNode.id = Date.now();

  console.log(newNode);
  console.log(d)

  if (d.data.children.length == 0) {
    console.log("i have no children")
    d.children = []
  }
  d.children.push(newNode)
  d.data.children.push(newNode.data)

  console.log(d)
  let foo = d3.hierarchy(parsedData, d => d.children) 
  drawLeft(foo, "left");
}


loadMindMap(parsedList);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few things going on:

#### Using Unique Keys

Using names isn't the best for keys, because each new node has the same name ("New Child"). Instead it's probably better to use some sort of ID system. Here's a quick function to tag the data for each node with an ID.

```
let currNodeId = 0;
function idData(node) {
  node.nodeId = ++currNodeId;
  node.children.forEach(idData);
}
idData(parsedList);
```

And since you're redefining the data in `parsedData`, you need to use the id property there too:

```
  parsedData = {
    "name": data.name,
    "nodeId": data.nodeId,
    "children": JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data.children.slice(split_index)))
  };
```

When adding a new node, you can also set it in the nodeData:

```
  var newNodeObj = {
    // name: new Date().getTime(),
    name: "New Child",
    nodeId: ++currNodeId,
    children: []
  };
```

Then to actually use `.nodeId` as the key for nodes, use it as the key function:

```
    .data(nodes, d => d.data.nodeId);
```

For links, you should use the `target` instead of the `source`, since this is a tree and there is only one link per child (instead of multiple links for one parent).

```
    .data(nodes, d => d.target.data.nodeId);
```

#### Prevent multiple node elements from being added

There's also an issue where you're merging your new and old nodes before adding new elements. To prevent this, you should change

```
node.enter().append("g").merge(node)
```

to:

```
node.enter().append("g")
```

#### Link transitions

Finally the transitions for your links are not transitioning with the nodes. To make them transition, move:

```
    .attr("d", d3.linkHorizontal()
      .x(d => d.y)
      .y(d => d.x));
```

to under

```
  linkUpdate.transition()
    .duration(750)
```

All together it looks like this: https://jsfiddle.net/v9wyb6q4/

Or:

```js
const widthMindMap = 700;
const heightMindMap = 700;
let parsedData;

let parsedList = {
  "name": " Stapler",
  "children": [{
      "name": " Bind",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "   Nail",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "   String",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": " Glue",
      "children": [{
          "name": "Gum",
          "children": []
        },
        {
          "name": "Sticky Gum",
          "children": []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": " Branch 3",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": " Branch 4",
      "children": [{
          "name": "   Branch 4.1",
          "children": []
        },
        {
          "name": "   Branch 4.2",
          "children": []
        },
        {
          "name": "   Branch 4.1",
          "children": []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": " Branch 5",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": " Branch 6",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": " Branch 7",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "   Branch 7.1",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "   Branch 7.2",
      "children": [{
          "name": "   Branch 7.2.1",
          "children": []
        },
        {
          "name": "   Branch 7.2.1",
          "children": []
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
let currNodeId = 0;
function idData(node) {
 node.nodeId = ++currNodeId;
  node.children.forEach(idData);
}
idData(parsedList);

let svgMindMap = d3.select('#div-mindMap')
  .append("svg")
  .attr("id", "svg-mindMap")
  .attr("width", widthMindMap)
  .attr("height", heightMindMap);


let backgroundLayer = svgMindMap.append('g')
  .attr("width", widthMindMap)
  .attr("height", heightMindMap)
  .attr("class", "background")

let gLeft = backgroundLayer.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + widthMindMap / 2 + ",0)")
  .attr("class", "g-left");
let gLeftLink = gLeft.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'g-left-link');
let gLeftNode = gLeft.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'g-left-node');


function loadMindMap(parsed) {
  var data = parsed;
  var split_index = Math.round(data.children.length / 2);

  parsedData = {
    "name": data.name,
    "nodeId": data.nodeId,
    "children": JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data.children.slice(split_index)))
  };

  var left = d3.hierarchy(parsedData, d => d.children);

  drawLeft(left, "left");
}

// draw single tree
function drawLeft(root, pos) {
  var SWITCH_CONST = 1;
  if (pos === "left") SWITCH_CONST = -1;

  update(root, SWITCH_CONST);
}

function update(source, SWITCH_CONST) {
  var tree = d3.tree()
    .size([heightMindMap, SWITCH_CONST * (widthMindMap - 150) / 2]);
  var root = tree(source);

  console.log(root)

  var nodes = root.descendants();
  var links = root.links();

  console.log(nodes)
  console.log(links)
  // Set both root nodes to be dead center vertically
  nodes[0].x = heightMindMap / 2

  //JOIN new data with old elements
  var link = gLeftLink.selectAll(".link-left")
    .data(links, d => d.target.data.nodeId)
    .style('stroke-width', 1.5);

  var linkEnter = link.enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", "linkMindMap link-left");

  var linkUpdate = linkEnter.merge(link);

  linkUpdate.transition()
    .duration(750)
    .attr("d", d3.linkHorizontal()
      .x(d => d.y)
      .y(d => d.x));
  var linkExit = link.exit()
    .transition()
    .duration(750)
    .attr('x1', function(d) {
      return root.x;
    })
    .attr('y1', function(d) {
      return root.y;
    })
    .attr('x2', function(d) {
      return root.x;
    })
    .attr('y2', function(d) {
      return root.y;
    })
    .remove();

  //JOIN new data with old elements
  var node = gLeftNode.selectAll(".nodeMindMap-left")
    .data(nodes, d => d.data.nodeId);

  console.log(nodes);

  
  //ENTER new elements present in new data
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", function(d) {
      return "nodeMindMap-left " + "nodeMindMap" + (d.children ? " node--internal" : " node--leaf");
    })
    .classed("enter", true)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
    })
    .attr("id", function(d) {
      let str = d.data.name;
      str = str.replace(/\s/g, '');
      return str;
    });

  nodeEnter.append("circle")
    .attr("r", function(d, i) {
      return 2.5
    });

  var addLeftChild = nodeEnter.append("g")
    .attr("class", "addHandler")
    .attr("id", d => {
      let str = d.data.name;
      str = "addHandler-" + str.replace(/\s/g, '');
      return str;
    })
    .style("opacity", "1")
    .on("click", (d, i, nodes) => addNewLeftChild(d, i, nodes));

  addLeftChild.append("line")
    .attr("x1", -74)
    .attr("y1", 1)
    .attr("x2", -50)
    .attr("y2", 1)
    .attr("stroke", "#85e0e0")
    .style("stroke-width", "2");

  addLeftChild.append("rect")
    .attr("x", "-77")
    .attr("y", "-7")
    .attr("height", 15)
    .attr("width", 15)
    .attr("rx", 5)
    .attr("ry", 5)
    .style("stroke", "#444")
    .style("stroke-width", "1")
    .style("fill", "#ccc");

  addLeftChild.append("line")
    .attr("x1", -74)
    .attr("y1", 1)
    .attr("x2", -65)
    .attr("y2", 1)
    .attr("stroke", "#444")
    .style("stroke-width", "1.5");

  addLeftChild.append("line")
    .attr("x1", -69.5)
    .attr("y1", -3)
    .attr("x2", -69.5)
    .attr("y2", 5)
    .attr("stroke", "#444")
    .style("stroke-width", "1.5");

  // .call(d3.drag().on("drag", dragged));;

  nodeEnter.append("foreignObject")
    .style("fill", "blue")
    .attr("x", -50)
    .attr("y", -7)
    .attr("height", "20px")
    .attr("width", "100px")
    .append('xhtml:div')
    .append('div')
    .attr("class", 'clickable-node')
    .attr("id", function(d) {
      let str = d.data.name;
      str = "div-" + str.replace(/\s/g, '');
      return str;
    })
    .attr("ondblclick", "this.contentEditable=true")
    .attr("onblur", "this.contentEditable=false")
    .attr("contentEditable", "false")
    .style("text-align", "center")
    .text(d => d.data.name);

  //TODO: make it dynamic
  nodeEnter.insert("rect", "foreignObject")
    .attr("ry", 6)
    .attr("rx", 6)
    .attr("y", -10)
    .attr("height", 20)
    .attr("width", 100)
    // .filter(function(d) { return d.flipped; })
    .attr("x", -50)
    .classed("selected", false)
    .attr("id", function(d) {
      let str = d.data.name;
      str = "rect-" + str.replace(/\s/g, '');
      return str;
    });

  var nodeUpdate = nodeEnter.merge(node);
  // Transition to the proper position for the node
  nodeUpdate.transition()
    .duration(750)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
    });

  // Remove any exiting nodes
  var nodeExit = node.exit()
    .transition()
    .duration(750)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
    })
    .remove();

  // On exit reduce the node circles size to 0
  nodeExit.select('circle').attr('r', 0);
  // node = nodeEnter.merge(node)
}

function addNewLeftChild(d, i, nodes) {
  console.log("make new child");
  event.stopPropagation();
  var newNodeObj = {
    // name: new Date().getTime(),
    name: "New Child",
    nodeId: ++currNodeId,
    children: []
  };
  
  console.log("this is ", parsedData)
  //Creates new Node
  var newNode = d3.hierarchy(newNodeObj);
  newNode.depth = d.depth + 1;
  newNode.height = d.height - 1;
  newNode.parent = d;
  newNode.id = Date.now();

  console.log(newNode);
  console.log(d)

  if (d.data.children.length == 0) {
    console.log("i have no children")
    d.children = []
  }
  d.children.push(newNode)
  d.data.children.push(newNode.data)

  console.log(d)
  let foo = d3.hierarchy(parsedData, d => d.children) 
  drawLeft(foo, "left");
}


loadMindMap(parsedList);
```

```css
.linkMindMap {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #555;
    stroke-opacity: 0.4;
}    
rect {
    fill: white;
    stroke: #3182bd;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;  
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
  <div id="div-mindMap">
```

Answer (score -1):

These sorts of problems usually arise because the key function which you pass as the second parameter to `selection.data()` is not unique or "too unique".

It should return a simple value which uniquely identifies each datum. In your case

```
.data(nodes, d => d);
```

might be better as

```
.data(nodes, d => d.name);
```

and similarly for the links.

However you will need to examine the output of `d3.tree` to see what fields the nodes and links have and which field contains a unique id.

Comment: Hi @Gordon! Thank you for responding! I've taken your suggestion, and made an edit (please look at my post to see the edit I have made). But as mentioned in the edit, there's some weird behavior going on. Could you please take a look and see what your thoughts are? I'm thinking though it uniquely identifies my data, it's causing some unwanted behavior, and I cannot figure out why.